# When is a nontrivial line bundle on a complex surface equivalent to an effective divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex surface i.e. $\dim_\mathbb C X = 2$ and let $D$ be a divisor on $X$ and $\mathcal O_X(D)$ its associated line bundle. I call two divisors $D, D'$ equivalent if $\mathcal O_X(D) \simeq \mathcal O_X(D')$ and a divisor is called effective if it is nonzero and all of its coefficients are nonnegative. The set of all nonnegative divisors equivalent to $D$ is denoted $|D|$.

My first question: is the fact that $\mathcal O_X(D)$ is not the trivial bundle sufficient to conclude that there exists an effective divisor equivalent to $D$?

I suspect not. The concrete situation I'm in is much more specific, but I don't see how to use its specificity. Namely, $X$ is projective and I am in the assumption that $\mathcal K_X^{\otimes 2}$ is not the trivial bundle, where $\mathcal K_X$ is the canonical bundle associated to $X$. I want to see that there exists an effective divisor in $|\mathcal K_X^{\otimes 2}|$. I can't for the life of me see why. I know that $|D| = \mathbb P( \Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X(D))) $ but I can't see how to deduce from the fact that $\mathcal K_X^{\otimes 2}$ is nontrivial that it admits global sections, nor how to see that if its space of global sections happens to have dimension $1$, then $|\mathcal K_X^{\otimes 2}|$ will contain an effective divisor, and not the zero divisor.

Comment: Without more conditions, this claim is false. For instance, take $X=\Bbb P^2$: then $K_X\cong \mathcal{O}(-3)$, so $K_X^{\otimes 2}\cong\mathcal{O}(-6)$ which has no nonzero global sections and is not linearly equivalent to any effective divisor. Can you provide more information on your specific problem?

Comment: The full data I have are that $X$ is minimal, $h^1(O_X) = 0$ and $kod(X) = 0$. I am looking at the three possibilities given in VI.3, p.193 of Barth et al., Compact Complex Surfaces. It is claimed that if $\mathcal K_X \neq 0$ and $\mathcal K_X^{\otimes 2} \neq 0$, then $|2K_X|$ contains an effective divisor. I thought the full data to be irrelevant for this claim.

Comment: Use Riemann- Roch. You will need most of the data in your comment.

Comment: @Mohan From RR I seem to get, using that $kod(X) = 0$ so $(K_X, K_X) = 0$, that $\dim H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes 2}) + \dim H^0(X, K_X^\vee) = \chi(X) + \dim H^1(X, K_X^{\otimes 2})$. I know the RHS is $\geq 1$ by $h^1(O_X) = 0$ but other than that I don't see what to do. I should be able to draw the conclusion that $\dim H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes 2}) \geq 2$, since I want $|2K_X|$ to contain at least two elements, right?

Comment: Why do you want two elements? Can you show that $h^0(-K)=0$?

Comment: You are right, I don't want two elements since I'm in the hypothesis that $K_X^{\otimes 2}$ is not trivial. But how do I show that $h^0(-K)=0$?